# Unknown tag jnlp warning in eclipse when dynamically creating a JNLP file using JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jnlp

I'm working on huge project that generates some jnlp files using JSP. While this is working fine, the validation in eclipse produces many warnings - beginning with `unknown tag jnlp` and many more `unknown attribute ...` for almost every line in the jsp.

My question: is there any way to get rid of those warnings without disabling validation of all jsp files? I.e. I still want to get warnings / errors for wrong jsp stuff in the jsp file, but don't want to get 50 warnings in that file because it generates jnlp stuff.

I don't want to change using jsp, but only change the configuration for jsp validation. Adding a custom tag library would be ok if that helps (I don't see how it could help or how to prevent the warnings here, it's just an idea). Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your JSP file declares that it generates XML and then reference the correct DTD/Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE jnlp PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc//DTD JNLP Descriptor 6.0//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/JNLP-6.0.dtd">
<jnlp>

</jnlp>
```

You won't can't get full XML validation, it will attempt to offer content assist.

Comment: Thanks, that makes most warnings go away - I was missing the doctype, the page directive was already there

Comment: @outofmind Ok so except the answer - or what is still missing?

Comment: @Lonzak testing is missing - but I guess the dynamically created jnlp will still be working after adding the doctype